Returning a value with multiple column criteria in Excel
I have a dataset that looks like the following...

And I'm looking to fill the table below using formulas...

Outcome...

I've tried doing an index match match but cannot get it to work on searching two columns rather than a column and a row. What is the formula I'm looking for?
I should note that maxifs and minifs will not work here since I have more specific Member/Measure variables that don't have these functions available.

MINIFS and MAXIFS.

Maybe show us the variables for which you cannot use MINIFS or MAXIFS

=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$10=$G2),--($B$2:$B$10=H$1),$C$2:$C$10) maybe?

@cybernetic.nomad - updated problem with more information.

With TOCOL function. Copy this array formula in the result table top-left cell and copy right/down in the table.
=INDEX($C$1:$F$20,TOCOL(IF((J$21=$B$1:$B$20)*($I22=$A$1:$A$20),ROW(C$1:F$20),1/0),3),MATCH(J$20,$C$1:$F$1,0))

Without TOCOL
=INDEX($C$1:$F$20,SUM(IF((J$21=$B$1:$B$20)*($I22=$A$1:$A$20),ROW(C$1:F$20))),MATCH(J$20,$C$1:$F$1,0))



This works great! Can you explain why the 1/0 and 3 are needed in the formula?

With this TOCOL filter out the not matching rows. 1/0 generates an error, while the number 3 defines to leave out Empty and Error values.

What if I want to pull in blank cells from the original table? Right now, blank cells return 0 but I want them to return as blanks.
